# Change strings in a dataframe-column by inserting a char on a specific position

Tags: python, pandas, string

In column 'date' i have strings in format yyyymm

I want to change these to format yyyy0mm

The code below solves the problem but is there a shorter,better way to do this ?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
  "date": ['202201','202202','202203'],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def change_date(row):
    str=row['date']
    str = str[:4] + "0" + str[4:]
    return str
df.date=df.apply (lambda row: change_date(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex:

```
# insert a 0 before the last 2 digits
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace(r'(?=\d{2}$)', '0', regex=True)
# variant: insert after first 4 digits
df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('(?<=^\d{4})', '0', regex=True)
```

Using concatenation:

```
# concatenate the first 4, 0, the rest
df['date'] = df['date'].str[:4] + '0' + df['date'].str[4:]
```

output:

```
      date  duration
0  2022001        50
1  2022002        40
2  2022003        45
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P6trqB/1)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df["data"]=df["date"].apply(lambda x:x[:-2]+"0"+x[-2:])
```

Comment: `apply` is really not needed here, pandas can vectorize this operation

Comment: true as you did in your answer good job